# Azure Snapshot Debugging and Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I've been trying to get Snapshot Debugging working with Azure functions all to no avail and was wondering if anyone else has had much joy with this.

In essence it seems very simple to get working (and it does work for azure websites) and just involves included a reference to Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.

However, try as I might, I cannot get it working for Azure functions. I've tried adding the same reference and using the telemetry client with TrackException and sure enough the exception appears in the Insight blade of the Portal, but I just get the 'Collect debug snapshots...' link rather than the 'Open debug snapshot' one.

thanks

Comment: I've tried a few more things one of which was to try and add a SnapShotTelemetryProcessor in directly, prior to using a telemetry client but alas it doesn't work. I'm either missing something obvious, or it's just not supported yet.

var builder = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
            
            builder.Use((next) => new SnapshotCollectorTelemetryProcessor(next));
            
            builder.Build();

Comment: Developer on Snapshot Debugger here. I know this reply is a bit late, but I'm sorry to say that, for now at least, the Snapshot Debugger is not supported in Azure Functions. Thanks for your interest, though. We will look into adding support in the future.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks very much for replying. I'll keep my eyes peeled and when there's an update I'll give it a go.

Comment: Shame, I was trying to get this set up too, thanks for the response @pharring

Comment: @pharring any update on Azure Function Snapshot Debugger??

Comment: @pharring, It has been implemented by Microsoft. check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Azure functions team has released a fix for this issue. You need to do two things.

- Install the NuGet package as in the link. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector
- Add the below code to host.Json and deploy your changes.

```
    {
   
      "version": "2.0",
      "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
          "snapshotConfiguration": {
            "IsEnabled": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

As of now only 2.x versions of .Net core is supported. Net framework works just fine.

[image]

For more details, see the issue, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24999

Answer (score 1):

Member of the Snapshot Debugger team,

To enable Snapshot Debugger in your Function app, you have to update your `host.json` file by adding the property `snapshotConfiguration` as defined below and redeploy your function.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "snapshotConfiguration": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Snapshot Debugger is pre-installed as part of the Azure Functions runtime, which by default it's disabled

Since Snapshot Debugger it's included in the Azure Functions runtime, it isn't needed to add extra NuGet packages nor application settings.

---

We have created the proper documentation of how to enable Application Insights Snapshot Debugger in Azure Function, see below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/snapshot-debugger-function-app

Renato Gutiérrez

[edited to include how to enable Snapshot Debugger snippet in the answer]

Comment: Although the Snapshot Collector is included in the Functions runtime, the current version seems to be 1.4.3, which is a year behind the current release, 1.4.4. It's probably worth installing the NuGet package to obtain the latest version. This was pointed out to me by the snapshot debugger troubleshooter in the Azure portal.